# Conditional XAML Crashes UWP App

Tags: xaml, uwp, conditional-statements

My UWP app targets a min version of 1703 and a max of 1803. It also uses an AcrylicBrush, which wasn't available until 1709. I'm trying to use conditional XAML to create an AcrylicBrush when the current version supports it (i.e. version is 1709 or higher).

Below I have a rectangle with the fill defined twice, once for anything before 1709, and once for 1709 and later. This code **works**.

**Edit**:

The code below should be Version1803 and Not1803. The answer from Rafael is right; Windows 10 Mobile 1709 will crash with this... but 1703 should not.... So for the sake of simplicity, just replace "1709" with "1803". With that said, does anyone know why it is crashing on 1703?

--end of edit.

```
xmlns:Version1709="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,5)"
xmlns:Not1709="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractNotPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,5)"

<Rectangle x:Name="AcrylicRectangle">
     <Version1709:Rectangle.Fill>
           <AcrylicBrush Opacity="0.5"></AcrylicBrush> 
    </Version1709:Rectangle.Fill>
    <Not1709:Rectangle.Fill>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Not1709:Rectangle.Fill>
 </Rectangle>
```

Here's the scoop: 1709 and newer have a transparent rectangle (because no color is set) and older than 1709 has a red rectangle, so far so good. This is where the problems start. You'll notice the only attribute I defined in AcrylicBrush is Opacity; any other defined attribute, like TintColor, TintOpacity, etc. will crash the app on 1703 Mobile. I've tried many different variations but they all have the same problem:

```
<AcrylicBrush Version1709:TintColor="Red" Opacity="0.5"></AcrylicBrush>
<AcrylicBrush TintColor="Red" Opacity="0.5"></AcrylicBrush>
<Version1709:AcrylicBrush Version1709:TintColor="Red" Opacity="0.5"></Version1709:AcrylicBrush>
<Version1709:AcrylicBrush TintColor="Red" Opacity="0.5"></Version1709:AcrylicBrush>
```

From the four AcrylicBrushes above I get this error at runtime on 1703 on Mobile:

Activation of the Windows Store app 'a77e7506-7031-4935-ad70-ef56585020de_h83rr06hb5xc0!App' failed with error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application.  This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted. More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output window (Debug->Windows->Output)'.
The program '[6928] [UWPAppName].exe' has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
When I say versions before 1709, that entails only 1703, since that is the minimum target. Conditional XAML isn't supported in versions earlier than 1703 (Build 15063) so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcrylicBrush` is not supported on Windows 10 Mobile's latest build.
The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush) specifies that AcrylicBrush is only available on Fall Creators Update 10.0.16299 which was never available for Mobile (latest version available is 10.0.15254.490).

I think the problem here is that AcrylicBrush is not avilable on the latest Mobile build.

Best option for you here is to create a class inheriting from `FrameworkElement` with the Attached DependencyProperties for the properties you need. Do the Contract level check in that class and update the background property with the appropriate brush based on that level.

Comment: Although you bring up a compelling point, one I hadn't considered, I don't think this explains the problem I am experiencing with Mobile build 15063. Based on your comment, I changed the conditions to Version1803 (for acrylic) and Not1803 (for regular), since Mobile never received 1803 and I don't have to worry about different build numbers like with 1709. It still does not work on 1703 Mobile.

Comment: @Mapplesoft I finally had some free time to try this. My answer above is still valid. The ```AcrylicBrush``` is only available on ```10.0.16299``` and newer. I attached a native debugger to the app instance running on my lumia 950xl (latest available win10 mobile build: 15254.490) and I got the following error: ```Unhandled exception at 0x6734D501 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in App2.exe...``` clearly what you are trying to do is not supported on mobile so my suggestion is to do this conditional check with C# code as suggested above.

Comment: I have resorted to version checking in C#. Seems like the app is trying to render the conditional XAML on mobile even when it shouldn't be. Can't figure out why. Works on different version of Windows 10 desktop though!

Comment: @Mapplesoft i think what might be happening is that the call engine is parsing the entire xaml file and when it reaches an element or attribute it doesn't know about it throws exceptions (native ones). I don't understand why it behaves this way. Quite possible this is a bug in XAML itself.